# Distribution of balls into boxes

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Is it possible to distribute 44 balls into 9 boxes with no box left empty and each containing different number of balls?

Comment: No... $1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9=45$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked answered:

As k99731 pointed out in a comment, this is not possible because the first $9$ natural numbers add up to $45$.

Indeed, if you were to suppose that you *could* do so, let the amount of balls in box $i$ be labeled $b_i$ and assume that the boxes are arranged in increasing order.

We have $b_2>b_1>0$, so $b_2\geq b_1+1$.  Similarly $b_3>b_2>b_1$ so $b_3\geq b_1+2$.  In general, we have $b_i\geq b_1+i-1$

We would require then that $44 = b_1+b_2+\dots+b_9 \geq 9b_1+ 36 \geq 45$, a contradiction.